# Why can't initialize values of struct out side of Main in C#

Tags: c#, struct

```
using System;
struct data
{
    public int x;
};

class testt
{

    data d;
    d.x =10; //Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
        
}

class test
{
    public static void Main(String[] ar)
    {
        data d;
        d.x = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(d.x);
    }
}
```

no problem while initializing in main function.When I Commented testt class pgm gives output.

Comment: Because the space in your program that's *outside* of a method (i.e. a function) is not executable code, it's just declarations, where each line does _not_ represent the next step of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via its constructor

```
class testt
{

    data d;
    public testt()
    {  
        d = new data(); // not needed as it's a struct
        d.x =10; 
    }  
}
```

Usage

```
var test = new testt();
```

Note : there is a lot to be desired with your current code.

1. You should use standard naming conventions and casing.
2. Use self descriptive names.
3. Use *explicit access modifiers* (i.e `public` / `private` / etc).
4. *Fields* should not be public unless you have a specific use case for it, and should likely be properties.
5. You should only use struct if you absolutely know you need them, and prefer classes.
6. If you do use a struct they should be *immutable*.

**Nonsensical example**

```
// immutable read-only struct
public readonly struct DogData
{
   // public property
   public int Length { get;}

   public DogData(int length)
   {
      Length = length;
   }
}

public class Dog
{
    // private field
    private DogData _dogData;
   
    // constructor
    public Dog()
    {  
        _dogData = new DogData(10); 
    }  
}
```